# Остановка в Бологое или в Бологом?

Tags: склонение, топонимика

Здравствуйте, уважаемые участники форума!

Столкнулась с проблемой: как правильно употребить название населенного пункта в предложении "Поезд проследует с остановкой в Болого(?)-м, или -е?" (Речь о городе в Тверской области). В сети не нашла конкретного ответа: правила не запрещают вариант "в Бологом", но местные жители очень против и настаивают на употреблении названия их города без всяких склонений. И, видимо, всё спорят, спорят...

Буду признательна за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Литературная  норма - *в Бологом*. "Бологое" - это субстантивированное существительное и склонятся должно как прилагательное среднего рода (ср. *большое село - в большом селе*). Другое дело, что сами жители этого уже поселка никогда название не склоняют, причем уже довольно давно. Моя бабушка, учительница русского языка и литературы, переехавшая туда в конце 50-х названия никогда не склоняла, то же самое касается и других моих родственников, уже без филологического образования, но родившихся там.

Comment: Большое спасибо за интересный ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Со стороны это название обычно склонялось и склоняется (в старой литературе можно встретить напр. у Лескова). Но жители воспринимают его как существительное. Для них это настолько важно, что в настоящее время оспаривается происхождение названия от старой формы русского прилагательного "благое" - в пользу иноязычного происхождения слова.

http://ecsocman.hse.ru/data/2012/06/19/1258580490/2.pdf

Comment: Спасибо за полезную информацию!

Answer (score 0):

Интересно почитать здесь:[Склонение, стр.8](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=605.rNlY8RcuPdKa9cw2fCjDyuYJnQejpets-lFCAAMG4BWJQ8tCvm_7ruiwU4J8WnjIdXfbKNz_1C2b2usPNW-s5Q.87112dfbc5ff11b07417b435a3e9d42810c1c5fd&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9XsMCv5TMMN9UTQSQbnFqxRfy1qNK6_no62JEFvW2UZjTibK6ICh6iYNbEoR8c-LynPH2mh_zXKXjId5KWWVUpYzxPQ-09tQaHSj5QzpDZ4oBcy5bg-fPBBwZnSkniBdSfcSSwknIzAbtgr_I80WhyVcjxmYVDjC_jbG2VACqTpnn-V39-EnKRFfNY_GpcTA-GSbNfR5wBQgUb4KATDttVDsiWyRUoGa75OWQSwJemPDQQ&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxclhUVzM1eE1wbjBzNDlldVFOaC0zMGtTcXBBekxVMkFzSjQ5Q1Y3Sm9ncjFyd0Z4dlNCYmc1bzJiSkI3bDdzenl6VjhVdUJWbXZsVUhiZ3lFMll5RW44QWNYVkpWYVlwUW9lNWQyc1VOMjE&b64e=2&sign=b151216159ebaaee2ad01dbe5a9f3090&keyno=0&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHtkusEOiLu3mdB1NJZzO2O5AA8OIHajtx9amFQSCzvJX93qLGKlmX7YmcB-WGN6mX6WZzWmZpXIt60DFGArzA9TspE2bO3Tyn1bgKwCuS6VIqeJNP7gqAaVjxNu0QYzOZaumW0362dBvAeU95Iv1LC2KbGlBq08vLAkH936itArjm_iEDPCANDA&l10n=ru&cts=1424434174864&mc=3.7900671274207163)